# Python and Elasticsearch autcompletion

Tags: python, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to work with Python Elasticsearch version 1.1.0, on the master branch. It seems it will create an index, but there are issues with retrieving autocomplete results, when using a suggestion filed.

Below is a basic Python functions to create an index, then add a song to it, and finally we query it through the curl at the very bottom.

Unfortunately it fails with the error:

```
"reason" : "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[music][2] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Field [suggest] is not a completion suggest field]; "
    } ]'
```

The functions I am using to create the index and add a song is below:

```
conn = Elasticsearch()

def mapping():
    return """{
          "song" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "name" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "suggest" : { "type" : "completion",
                                  "index_analyzer" : "simple",
                                  "search_analyzer" : "simple",
                                  "payloads" : true
                    }
                }
            }
        }"""

def createMapping():
    settings = mapping()
    conn.indices.create(index= "music", body=settings)

def addSong():
    body = """{
        "name" : "Nevermind",
        "suggest" : {
            "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
            "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
            "payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },
            "weight" : 34
        }
    }"""

    res = conn.index(body=body, index="music", doc_type="song", id=1)
```

Curl request:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/music/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
    "song-suggest" : {
        "text" : "n",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [create index API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings), you have to wrap your mappings in `mappings`:

```
def createMapping():
    settings = """{"mappings": %s}""" % mapping()
    conn.indices.create(index= "music", body=settings)
```